# Generate XML with namespace for each element

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb, xml-namespaces

How can I generate XML with the following schema using JAXB.

```xml
<NS1:getRatesResponse xmlns:NS1="http://mynamespaceTypes">
    <response>
        <NS2:rates xmlns:NS2="http://mynamespace">
            <currency>USD</currency>

        </NS2:rates>
        <NS3:rates xmlns:NS3="http://mynamespace">
            <currency>EUR</currency>
            
        </NS3:rates>
        <NS4:rates xmlns:NS4="http://mynamespace">
           ... etc
    </response>
</NS1:getRatesResponse>
```

I don't know how to tell JAXB that every new item should be NS(n+1) with the same namespace. Changing XML format is not an option, because it's external.

JAXB parses this XML correctly, but when producing using same classes it produces it like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:getRatesResponse
   xmlns:ns2="http://mynamespaceTypes" 
   xmlns:ns3="http://mynamespace">
  <response>
    <ns2:rates>
     <currency>EUR</currency>
     
    </ns2:rates>
    <ns2:rates>
     <currency>USD</currency>
     
    </ns2:rates>
  </response>
 </ns3:getRatesResponse>
```

Comment: The external consumer _requires_ all those extra namespace declarations?! Ewww! Get a new external consumer.

Comment: Yeah, i know it`s horrible. But i can`t do anything with it, it`s a proprietary internal bank system.

Comment: Yeah, I know you're stuck. That's why I did it as a comment, not an answer. (If you're truly stuck, substitute into a string template and hate your life. At least the data's probably simple enough to make this not very problematic.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this use case I would do the following:

1. Create a StAX `XMLStreamWriter`
2. Write the `getRatesResponse` and `response` elements directly to the `XMLStreamWriter`
3. Set the following property on `marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);` to prevent the header from being written on each marshal call.
4. Marshal each of the `Rate` objects to the `XMLStreamWriter` individually.
5. On the Marshaller set an instance of `NamespacePrefixMapper` on it to control the namespace prefix (this currently requires the JAXB RI, support for this extension is currently being added to [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)).

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html

Comment: How can i generate numbered prefixes in NamespacePrefixMapper ? As i see it`s get as parameters namespace and suggested prefix. How would i know in generate method what element number is it, and i need to know to generate prefixes ns2,ns3,ns4,etc.. I maybe i`m missing something? Can you provide an example of using NamespacePrefixMapper  to achieve what i need?

Comment: In this approach each instance of `Rate` will be treated as a separate marshal.  This means you have the opportunity to affect the instance of `NamespacePrefixMapper` between marshal calls.

Comment: Ah, yep, correct. But when i marshell each Rate individually to created XMLStreamWriter i get this error: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Can not output XML declaration, after other output has already been done. 
Look like jaxb tried to output <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>. How to tell him not to do this?

Comment: You will need to set the following property on `marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);`

Comment: The namespace uri and namespace prefix are read from the database and during marshalling the namespace prefix and namespace uri need to be added in the generated XML. I think, dynamically, I cannot change the @XmlRootElement annotation's namespace value. Is it possible to add namespace uri and namespace prefix during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Adding these config to my scheme solved my issue
attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"

Comment: That is unlikely to do what the OP is asking for.